# If $f_n \stackrel{\text{unif}}{\longrightarrow} f$, do we have $\int_{0}^{1-1/n} f_n \to \int_0^1 f$ where $f_n \in \mathcal C[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence

> Suppose $f_n \stackrel{\text{unif}}{\longrightarrow} f$ (uniform convergence) on $[0,1]$ where $f_n \in \mathcal C[0,1]$. Do we have $\int_{0}^{1-1/n} f_n \to \int_0^1 f$? Here, $\mathcal C[0,1]$ is the space of all continuous functions on $[0,1]$.

I write this post for two reasons: (i) to verify my solution and (ii) to see other ways to approach this problem.

---

Define $F(x) = \int_0^x g(x) dx$ and $F_n(x) = \int_0^1 g_n(x)dx$. Since $f_n \stackrel{\text{unif}}{\longrightarrow} f$, we have $F_n(x)\to F(x)$. What can we say about $F_n(1-\frac1n)$? I feel since $1 - \frac1n \to 1$ as $n\to\infty$, and $F_n(x)\to F(x)$, we must have $F_n(1-\frac1n) \to F(1) = 
\int_0^1 f(x)dx$. However, I'm not able to properly justify this. Since $f_n$ (integrand) and $1-1/n$ (the upper limit) both depend on $n$, I feel we may need some extra bit of reasoning.

---

Minor follow-up question:
Since $f$ and $f_n$'s are bounded (continuous functions on compact sets), is there a way to use Dominated Convergence Theorem here? I understand the posted answer though!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left|\int_0^{1-1/n}{f_n}-\int_0^1{f}\right| =\left|\int_0^{1-1/n}{(f_n-f)} -\int_{1-1/n}^1{f}\right| \leq \int_0^{1-1/n}{|f_n-f|}+\int_{1-1/n}^1{|f|} \leq \|f_n-f\|_{\infty}+\frac{1}{n}\|f\|_{\infty},$$ which concludes (since $f$ is bounded, by eg $\|f_{n_0}\|_{\infty}+1$, where $n_0>0$ is such that $\|f_{n_0}-f\|_{\infty}\leq 1$).

Comment: Would it be $$\frac{n-1}{n}\|f_n-f\|_{\infty}+\frac{1}{n}\|f\|_{\infty}$$ instead? Then one may conclude  $$\frac{n-1}{n}\|f_n-f\|_{\infty}+\frac{1}{n}\|f\|_{\infty} < \|f_n-f\|_{\infty}+\|f\|_{\infty}$$
Just want to know if you've intentionally skipped this step. Also, why is $f$ bounded?

Comment: @epsilon-emperor check that $\frac{n-1}{n}\le1$. So it still makes sense.

Comment: @epsilon_delta Yes, it does make sense. I just wanted to know if that step was skipped for a reason. Also, we can get rid of the $1/n$ in the second term as well (which I think Mindlack wanted to do).

Comment: @epsilon-emperor $f_n$ is uniformly to $f$. So, $f$ is continuous since $f_n$ are continuous.

Comment: @epsilon-emperor: yes, I purposefully skipped that step because the $1/n$ doesn’t bring anything. I explained why $f$ is bounded at the end of my answer. Short version is that $f$ is a uniform limit of continuous functions so is continuous. A more ad hoc argument is in my answer.

Comment: @Mindlack Can we say that since $f$ is continuous, it maps the compact domain $[0,1]$ to a compact set? Compact sets are closed and **bounded** in $\mathbb R$, which is what we want. Right?

Comment: @epsilon-emperor you can’t estimate $1/n$ by $1$. Because then the result you want you may not get. You need to show the left hand quantity of above to be very small.

Comment: @epsilon_delta: thanks a lot for explaining the answer better than I do. :) For epsilon-emperor: yes, that’s how you use the continuity of $f$.

Comment: I still don't see why the RHS goes to zero. It should go to zero in order to prove what we want, right? I see no other way. Please help!

Comment: Hey, no need for yelling, we’re right here (and you really can figure this one out on your own, but never mind). $\|f_n-f\|_{\infty}$ goes to zero because $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly, while $\frac{\|f\|_{\infty}}{n} \rightarrow 0$ is well-known (because $1/n$ goes to zero).